# Updating git svn info/revision number for git repo (A) cloned from git-svn repo (B)

Tags: git, git-svn, revision-history

Okay, I am *not* asking how to synch the changes back and forth between the two repos (I am able to do that via normal push and pull), but a way to update the git svn info (particularly the revision number) for (A) from (B)

Currently I can do that not-so-elegantly by taking the first line with "git-svn-id:" from the output of `git log`, but looking for better ideas that possibly address the root cause that I may not be aware of..

Update:

For the revision number I can obtain that via `git log --grep=git-svn-id: -1` and use of filterchains in ant, so my immediate problem is solved.

As for the question itself, based on information from [here](http://blogs.coreboot.org/blog/2010/08/27/git-svn-info-unable-to-determine-upstream-svn-information-from-working-tree-history/), it seems that there is no point in doing what I want to do, so I may have to close this question after some time.

Comment: "a way to update the git svn info" - what does this mean? Do you want to be able execute 'git svn info' command with meaningful output inside A-repo?

Comment: @the.malkolm It should be able to update the information just like the way B-repo does. Right now it only has the contents that were accurate at the time of first cloning of B to A.

Comment: so you want to init git-svn inside clone (A) too?

Comment: not too sure what you mean by that... I was only looking for a way to sync the contents for git svn info and git svn log from B over to A. Right now, I am getting the idea that B only appears as a regular git repo to A, which is really a git clone of a git clone, and there's no way to "git-svn clone" a git-svn clone. So what I want is not possible through normal means of using git-svn.

Comment: Yep, there is no way with normal workflow. It's possible to initialize the same git-svn branch inside A. Will it work?

Comment: related: http://subtlegradient.com/articles/2008/04/22/cloning-a-git-svn-clone.html